# PHP Header location vs JavaScript Redirect

Tags: javascript, php

I am currently developing a website for my bachelor's thesis, and from my previous experience, bad use of `header('Location: http://www.example.com/');` can end up pretty messy at times.

My question is: When or how is it good to use `header('Location: http://www.example.com/');` vs. using `window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");`?

An example: let's say we have a registration script, and after it's done, it will redirect the user towards `index.php`. Which of those is better to use, and how?

Comment: The Javascript method requires that the client first load the response, parse it all, execute the JS, then load the destination of the redirect. The `header` method just goes there directly.

Comment: However, it give you more flexibility -- you can display something before redirecting.

Comment: This is part opinionated/part situational. If you're using ajax, then javascript is the way to go. If not, then use header if you don't want anything else to be submitted to the user.

Comment: To avoid opinion-based solutions ask yourself this: Does your application *require* the redirect to happen.  If it does; PHP is your best bet.  JavaScript can be disabled by the user; a PHP redirect cannot.

Comment: @RobertC that does indeed shed some light. All the time I was debating this with myself I ignored the possibility of disabling JS. Thank you.

Comment: I can think of basically *no* situation where I'd use a JavaScript redirect - if you're coming back from an Ajax response it seems a bit counter-productive to load another page rather than update the DOM of the one you're on. Whereas I use 302 header redirects from PHP (after form submission for instance) a *lot*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would personally always recommend a PHP redirect over a JS one.

The messiness you ascribe to PHP redirects, I believe can only occur when you neglect to terminate the script immediatley afterwards, or you've allowed output to occur before issuing your header. The latter is a problem you need to solve sure, but the former:

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
exit;
```

Is very easy to solve.

A JavaScript redirect includes significantly more work for both your server and your visitor: the entire page has to be built by your server and sent to your user. The browser will start to download linked images, scripts and stylesheets before the redirect hits. On top of this, you need to hope your visitor hasn't disabled JavaScript.

TL;DR: PHP is faster, and consumes less server resources and bandwidth

Comment: Well, the supposedly `create_account.php` script will contain just the instructions needed for the server to send the data to the database, and no more than that. It would be a blank page if left to load fully. I take it it's better to use `header('Location');`  in such situations where nothing can follow the redirection?

And what if I want to redirect if successful, or display a message if not? 
I usually did that by sending a `&reg=ok` or `&reg=error_x` to display an according message on the redirected page.

Comment: Or, let's say redirect if user not logged in, or display the page otherwise?

Comment: That would be conditional logic around your redirect. Some pseudocode: `if($success) { header('location: /some-page'); exit; } /* code here to display page telling user to sort themselves out */`

Comment: I was using that, except not placing the `exit;` command after the redirect. I finally got it, I guess. Thanks a lot, man!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you implement the registration, if you use typical form to send user’s credentials to server, then after authentication you should use PHP header Location.

If you send user’s credentials through JavaScript to an api , the api would authenticate them and send a json data response back, in this occasion use JavaScript redirect.

Comment: I am using the typical form to send user's credentials to the script. Forgot to mention that, but it's been solved, though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The first case will fail when JS is off. It's also a little bit slower since JS must be parsed first (DOM must be loaded). However JS is safer since the destination doesn't know the referer and your redirect might be tracked (referers aren't reliable in general yet this is something).

result is same for all options(Header location vs JavaScript Redirect):
the  in the html page:

- Show content of your site, and next redirect user after a few (or 0)
  seconds.
- Don't need JavaScript enabled.
- Don't need PHP.

**on JS**

- Javascript enabled needed
- Don't need PHP.
- Show content of your site, and next redirect user after a few (or 0)
  seconds.

**in PHP:**
Redirect will be executed first, user never see what is after. header() must be the first command in php script, before output any other. If you try output some before header, will receive an **Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent**

Comment: That was the error I was getting, and had to trouble myself so much with it since a lot of my scripts had badly placed PHP redirects all around them.

Comment: @RăzvanTruță If you're seeing that error a lot, consider wrapping your entire process in `ob_start();` (at the very start) and `echo ob_get_clean();` (at the very end)